# how to learn? What resources to start looking at

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tutorial, education, paint.net

I am kind of just starting out in learning how to create interesting monochrome designs in Paint.net.

Now, I can learn the technique in just about application.  What I would like to know is where (online / free) I can learn how to make some decent graphics for a simple android app that I'm making....

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by monochrome designs? Do you have an example? As it is, this feels a little too broad. Have you tried any techniques? What kind of app are you making and where are you stuck? The more information you share, the easier it is to help :)

Comment: im trying to make some simple icons / badges for an android app.  really I am somewhat familiar with paint tools - I just don't how how to make these simple types of images in an efficient way (I can hack it, but really I want to learn how to create better images rather than something Im trying to make look like it was made correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what u need is Inkscape

Is free open-source and is easy to use and help a lot when u r doing an app

There is a lot of information an training examples in their oficial Web page try it..